# How to make the "wipe" transition with vertical line in Premiere pro cs6?

Tags: premiere, adobe, transitions

How to make the "wipe" transition with vertical line dividing the image during transition in Premiere pro cs6?

Transitions like that is most often used in the demoreels, showing process of creating shots "in layers"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your idea. Simplest way is using a **Linear Wipe** Effect (on the strip above). For more complex transitions I'd suggest to animate a **rectangular mask path** in order to get most control, see the manual: https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/masking-tracking.html

Comment: Thank you very much! :)  And thanks for the link, very useful information for me! 

And I also found one more way to do it, I'll leave it here as the second answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you double-click on transition "wipe", in the timeline,

[image]

at the "source window" will appear settings of the transition.

There you can adjust the width and color of the border, which will be visible as a vertical strip on the border of the transition.

[image]